# How to download a Dota 2 live game?

Tags: dota-2

Sometimes I want to download live games, usually I would visit one of the players' profile and download their previous games, so when the game ends I would have access to it. However this time none of the players have oxposed their matchmaking data (set their profile as private). How can I download such match?

Comment: You want to download a replay that none of the players want to share?

Comment: What they did not share is their public matching data, not the game itself, I just need to figure out its match ID.

Comment: ...which would give you their matching data. I don't think we should be helping you access something none of the players want to share.

Comment: @Frank That does not mean that the game is not public and therefore this is not intruding at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only got a few options here as far as I know:

If you know friends who play with him constantly and their profile is not private you can check their games via dotabuff (or other statsites), take the matchID you want and search for it in the DotA 2 client.

You need to guess which games are most likely played by the player in the context of friends.

In the DotA 2 client however you can see the real names of the players and download the replay up until 8 days in advance.